# Handwriting/drawing in Angular 2/Ionic 2 app?

Tags: mobile, angular, typescript, ionic2, handwriting

I need to capture a hand signature from the user written in the screen of a mobile device with a stylus.

The result should be stored as a vectorial or bitmap image.

How could I do this? Is there some library for typescript?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Signature Pad](https://github.com/szimek/signature_pad) library. Please take a look at [this demo](http://szimek.github.io/signature_pad/).

You can also find a tutorial [here](https://devdactic.com/signature-drawpad-ionic/) (it's for angular1, but it may help as well).